# How to create my own data list like a Listview? (Xamarin.forms)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making app with Xamarin.forms. 
I want to make my own data list like a listview. 
But it doesn't seem like a listview but each items will be located like circle.

You can imagine an Apple Watch's UI.

and I really want to make it having functionality and flexible like a ListView that can detect well changed data.

So, I want to set 'ItemSources' from my ObservableCollection. 
But If I do this with using BindableProperty, I only can detect when ObservableCollection object is assigned. (I also want to detect when it's item is changed.)

What document or article should I look?

Everything I searched so far is about just customizing a ListView.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your UI to be notified when a property's value changes, then each item in your `ObservableCollection` needs to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/), and your UI needs to listen for `PropertyChanged` events.

Comment: I figured it out with adding CollectionChanged from ObservableCollection. So I can check added or removed objects and handle that. And for items, I just using binding and it works automatically.